# objective-c regular expressions match

Tags: objective-c, regex

If I have contiguous sentences and i want to match every of them, ex:

> [symbol]bla bla bla bla[/symbol][symbol]text text text[/symbol]

i tried to math them like this :

> "\[symbol].*[/symbol]]"

but it returned me the full string, how to match every part of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use

- `*?` - This will match as few as possible characters
- I'm assuming that, in the results, you don't want the `[symbol]` and `[/symbol]`, but rather just the text in-between. Thus, you can to use "capturing parentheses" to specify what to return.
- You also want to "quote" the `[` and `/` characters with backslash.

This yields:

```
\[symbol](.*?)\[\/symbol]
```

Obviously, when you want to represent `\` in a string, though, you need to use `\\`. So that yields:

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[symbol](.*?)\\[\\/symbol]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
if (!regex) {
    NSLog(@"regex error: %@", error);
}

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *foundString = [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]]; // use result.range if you want to include the `[symbol]` and `[/symbol]`
    NSLog(@"%@", foundString);
}];
```

That produces:

```
2014-10-16 01:32:26.680 MyApp[66822:303] bla bla bla bla
2014-10-16 01:32:26.681 MyApp[66822:303] text text text
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using a lazy `.*?` pattern

`\[symbol\].*?\[\/symbol\]`

will match

`[symbol]bla bla bla bla[/symbol]`

if you want to match all of them seperatly use a `global(g)` specifier

which will match seperatly

```
[symbol]bla bla bla bla[/symbol]
[symbol]text text text[/symbol]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex it will match want you want.

```
\[symbol\]((?:(?!\[\/?symbol\]).)*)\[\/symbol\]
```

See DEMO:
http://regex101.com/r/aR7cG7/1